# I want to read whatever book that he wrote

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, I think "whatever" itself introduces the relative clause, so you shouldn't put another relative pronoun "that."

What do you think about my idea?

Answer (score 0):

"I want to read whatever book he wrote" is the correct way of putting it. It sounds a bit irritable, though. As in:

YOU. I want to read his book about butterflies.
THEY. He hasn't written anything like that.
YOU. How about hockey? Is his book about hockey?
THEY. No. He dislikes hockey.
YOU. But he has written a book?
THEY. Yes.
YOU. And it's not about opera, either?
THEY. Nope.
YOU. Fine. Whatever. I want to read whatever book he wrote. Where can I buy it?

Something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct:

> I want to read whatever book he wrote

and

> I want to read the book that he wrote

are both fine, but

> I want to read whatever book that he wrote

is not.

See the usage of "whatever" as an adjective [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whatever):

> 6. in any amount; to any extent:
>    *whatever merit the work has.*
> 7. no matter what:
>    *whatever rebuffs he might receive.*
> 8. being what or who it may be:
>    *Whatever the reason, he refuses to go.*
> 9. of any kind (used as an intensifier following the noun or pronoun it modifies):
>    *any person whatever.*

As you can see, "whatever rebuffs" and "whatever merit" are both correct usages, without needing to involve "that".

Answer (score 0):

The directive requiring a reduced restrictive relative clause after a noun with determiner *whatever* appears to be a particular bugaboo of the *[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=whatever)*:

> When a noun followed by a restrictive clause is preceded by
>   *whichever* or *whatever*, **it is regarded** as incorrect to introduce the clause with that in formal writing: *whatever book that
>   you want to look at*; one should write instead *Whatever book you want
>   to look at will be sent to your office* or *Whichever book costs less*
>   (not *that costs less*) *is fine with us.*

Not only does the *AHD* hide behind the **passive** (Who regards this as a rule?), but there's no explanation as to why the determiners *whatever* and *whichever* are the only ones singled out.  It's certainly easy enough to find authors who violate the *AHD* rule in formal writing.  This from [*The First U.S. History Textbooks: Constructing and Disseminating the American Tale in the Nineteenth Century*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uMx_CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=%22whichever%20book%20that%22&source=bl&ots=2cUD8FaeTf&sig=tzw6EwFobP623Wm4G_urFPYL5AA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie_Yjf0KnJAhVMRiYKHSX7BSMQ6AEIJzAD#v=onepage&q=%22whichever%20book%20that%22&f=false) by Barry Joyce:

> Everyone, **whichever book that they owned**, was ultimately reading that
>   same story. And for the first five decades of the nineteenth century,
>   few Americans objected.

The google records about 22.5K hits for "whichever book" and about 14.5K hits for "whichever book that."  This is an imperfect measure, but when two-thirds of online examples seem to violate the rule, you have to wonder whether the regard for this rule extends beyond the usage committee at the *AHD*.